# How can I get the name of last called operator

Tags: python

I'm trying to get what operator had been called before the current operator and make some logic based on that. Is this information accessible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blender records all operator calls in `WindowManager.operators` list: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.operators

```
import bpy

ops = bpy.context.window_manager.operators
print(ops)
# <bpy_collection[46], WindowManager.operators>
```

To get the second-to-last operator name in the list, you can use negative indices and `Operator.name` to get the name: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.name

```
print(ops[-1].name) # last operator name
print(ops[-2].name) # second to last operator name

# Join
# Move
```

... same for `Operator.bl_idname`: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.bl_idname

```
print(ops[-1].bl_idname) # last operator bl_idname
print(ops[-2].bl_idname) # second to last operator bl_idname

# OBJECT_OT_join
# TRANSFORM_OT_translate
```

Comment: Is there any way to re-do the operators from this list? Basically I wanted to push the most recent operator onto a queue (filtered with some options), then repeat those actions. Basically do bpy.ops["bl_idname first part"]["bl_idname second part"]()